# why doesn't the div spread the entire div container?

Tags: css

i want the background of a div to change on hover. However on hover, the doesn't change the entire div background color (reason the div width doesnt cover the entire width of the div it is contained in). Could you please let me know how to fix it. Below is the code snippet,

```
.list_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  ul {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
      li {
        .list {
          margin: 0;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          &:hover {
            background-color: green;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

<div className="list_container">
  <header>
    <h4>Listitems</h4>
  </header>
  <ul>
      <li>
        <div className="list"><span>hello</span></div>
          <ul>
             <li>
                <div className="list"><span>hello</span></div>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The div with classname list doesnt spread the width of entire div it is contained in (that is lists). The list items are added dynamically. So as the list items grow...the div with class list doesnt cover the entire div list_container. How can i fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Please start by fixing your HTML markup it's a mess

Comment: Your markup is invalid and you need to address that first, and if you don't know what that is, you need to take a course before moving on.

Comment: @SuperDJ this is a react code, so if you want to put it in a snippet you should convert it to a correct HTML.

Comment: Your invalid markup needs to be the first thing you fix. A <ul>'s first descendent will always be an <li>. For future reference, use the w3.org's html validator to identify issues in your markup. https://validator.w3.org/